# How to indicate that I am an ERC reviewer in CV?

Tags: peer-review, cv

I would like to indicate in my CV that I am a reviewer for the European Research Commission. Would something like this work?

```
Other professional experience
• Reviewer for Science, bla bla bla...
• Reviewer of European Research Council (ERC) proposals.
```

Thank you

Comment: That's fine. If you are short on space, you can list it together with the journals (Reviewer for Science, ERC, Nature, ...).

Answer (score 6):

I think it is pretty common to list such reviewing activities in CVs, at least I've seen it often. Usually, people list these activities under "Service", as in "volounteer service to the academic community".

However, I don't think these things are actually very important, especially at your (presumed) career stage: if you are an ERC reviewer, you must be pretty well known, maybe already a Full Prof. (or Associate), thus these details won't make your career any better, in my opinion. They might have more of an impact for junior people, as it means they are recognised as experts by the community, which, with less years under the belt, might be a relatively nice accomplishment.

Comment: Thank you, I agree that this is not going to make a big difference.